# openerp schedule server action

Tags: python, odoo

In OpenERP 6.0.1, I've created a server action to send a confirmation email after an invoice is confirmed, and linked it to appropriately to the invoice workflow. now normally when an invoice is confirmed, an email is automatically sent.
is there a way to set a date for when the email should be sent instead of being sent immediately? like "send email after one week of confirmation" ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a one object `ir.cron` which will run on specific time period. There you can specify the time when you want to sent the mail.

This object will call the function which you given in `Method` attribute. In this function you have to search for those invoices which are in `created` state. Then check the date when it created and if its >=7 days then send mail.

**Or**

You can create `ir.cron` on specific workflow action of the invoice which will have `Next Execution Date` as after the 7 or 8 days.

Comment: thanks Lafada im familiar with the ir.cron object as we use it to create monthly invoices based on pro-forma invoices, but i was hoping to modify the email server action itself (or the invoice workflow) so that it would accommodate a send-date. nevertheless I'll go with ur method it's more logical.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know but i think you can also use the sheduled actions in administration->shedular->sheduled actions or else ir.cron is the best option for sheduling outgoing emails

Answer (score 0):

With OpenERO 6.1 New Email Engine has Email Queue so what you just need to do it queue your Email on that email queue and we already have one Scheduled Action which processes this email  queue at defined interval, so what you can do it you can change the trigger time of the same action. and you can see the email Engine api for how to queue your emails in email queue.

Regards